# Does latest MacBook Air have powered USB ports?

Tags: usb, macbook-pro, power

I see that the latest 13 inch MacBook Air has two USB 2.0 ports, but can they power, say, a 2.5 inch external hard drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the USB ports are powered. In fact, they are designed to power the [USB SuperDrive](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB397G/A), which draws more power than most USB ports support.